# How to detect objects in an image using single reference image of each object?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

TL DR;
I want to detect where products on the shelf are, using given images of each product.

I initially thought of using a detector but no annotations were given. I also looked for weakly supervised object detection techniques but they don't solve my problem completely.